# DJANGO Queryset filter according to inner calculations on nested model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with the following fields:

> - required_visits : a positive integer
> - person - another model with: name,age,curr_week_visits

I would like to filter all the rows in which the following calculation is true:

> required_visits__minus__person__curr_week_visits__gt=0

in words: the model's required visits minus the person's current weeks visits is bigger than 0

What is the right way to write this filter queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`annotation with F() expression`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations):

```
from django.db.models import F

ModelName.objects.annotate(
    visit_difference=F('required_visits') - F('person__curr_week_visits')
).filter(visit_difference__gt=0)
```

Comment: Thats awsome, one problem though: i get the following exception now: "Exception Value: (1690, "BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range"

Comment: Never mind - solved the new issue using annotations casting as shown in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#cast